# How to convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into Vector

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, k-means

I'm completely new to Spark and currently I'm trying to use Python to write a simple code that does KMeans on a set of data.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import re
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
from numpy import array
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler

import pandas as pd
import numpy
df = pd.read_csv("/<path>/Wholesale_customers_data.csv")
sql_sc = SQLContext(sc)
cols = ["Channel", "Region", "Fresh", "Milk", "Grocery", "Frozen", "Detergents_Paper", "Delicassen"]
s_df = sql_sc.createDataFrame(df)
vectorAss = VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols, outputCol="feature")
vdf = vectorAss.transform(s_df)
km = KMeans.train(vdf, k=2, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="k-means||")
model = kmeans.fit(vdf)
cluster = model.clusterCenters()
print(cluster)
```

I typed these into pyspark shell, and when it runs model = kmeans.fit(vdf), I got the following errors:

> TypeError: Cannot convert type into Vector
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
>   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at
>   org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:275) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:88)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 17/02/26 23:31:58 ERROR
>   Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 23.0 (TID 113)
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 111, in main process() File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 106, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index,
>   iterator), outfile) File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 263, in dump_stream vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
>   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/linalg/init.py", line 77, in _convert_to_vector raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s
>   into Vector" % type(l)) TypeError: Cannot convert type into Vector The

data I got is from: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00292/Wholesale%20customers%20data.csv

Could someone please tell me what is going wrong here and what I missed? I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

UPDATE:
@Garren
The errors I got is:

> The errors I got is: >>> kmm = kmeans.fit(s_df)17/03/02 21:58:01 INFO
>   BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on localhost:56193 in
>   memory (size: 5.8 KB, free: 511.1 MB) 17/03/02 21:58:01 INFO
>   ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 5 17/03/02 21:58:01 INFO
>   BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_0_piece0 on localhost:56193 in
>   memory (size: 5.8 KB, free: 511.1 MB) 17/03/02 21:58:01 INFO
>   ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 4
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 69,
>   in fit
>       return self._fit(dataset)   File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 133,
>   in _fit
>       java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)   File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line 130,
>   in _fit_java
>       return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)   File "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 813, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in
>   deco
>       raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'features' given
>   input columns: [Channel, Grocery, Fresh, Frozen, Detergents_Paper,
>   Region, Delicassen, Milk];"

Comment: In which line are you getting error?

Comment: Hi Vivek, the line is: model = kmeans.fit(vdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Spark 2.x ML package exclusively over the [soon to be deprecated] spark mllib package:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("whole_customers_data.csv")
cols = df.columns
vectorAss = VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols, outputCol="features")
vdf = vectorAss.transform(df)
kmeans = KMeans(k=2, maxIter=10, seed=1)
kmm = kmeans.fit(vdf)
kmm.clusterCenters()
```

Comment: Hi Garren, Could you share you code? I ran the code and got errors.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hpnhxxwn I will share the code in my updated answer. Please also post your errors so that others can learn from them too.

Comment: @hpnhxxwn Glad it worked for you! Please mark the answer as accepted. I suspect some of the trouble may have come from trying to mix the Spark 2.x ML with the old spark mllib. I see your update says "features" is missing and that appears to be at least in part because you used `outputCol = "feature"` without the "s"